# How to fetch the $_GET or $_POST value for a Laravel Query

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Okay, I tried searching the solution for getting values from the form and inserting into the Laravel Query Builder, but I haven't found the answer yet.

So, if I am building a query

```
->where ('company.city', '=', $form_value_for_city)
```

How can I get the value for $form_value_for_city passed by the form in a POST or GET request.

Something equivalent of getting value like

```
$form_value_for_city = $_GET["city"]
```

I am aware about Laravel's security standards, but what is the exact way of passing the value in a query from a form submission.

Comment: Do you have a controller at all? Have you setup your routes?

Comment: Yes, I have a controller which calls Illuminate\Http\Request, so using the request object worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use request object to get post and get values:

```
request()->get('variable_name');
```

If you pass a parameter with the type of Illuminate\Http\Request to your controller method you can use that instead:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request    

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->all(); //returns all values
    $request->has('variable_name'); // check for existance
    $request->get('variable_name'); // get the value
}
```

It is ok to pass the data from a form directly to Larave query builder methods. Because Laravel’s Eloquent ORM uses PDO parameter binding to avoid SQL injection. So you can safely do `->where ('company.city', '=', $request->city)`.

Comment: Perfect, this works for me. One question though why would you use the store function, if we are calling request object and getting the variable name.

Comment: It is an example. You can use any name for your function.

Comment: I have another question, in Laravel if I am getting the value from a column name which has a hyphen.  {{$company->start-time}} how can I call it? Because it's giving me an error currently.

Comment: It is not a good practice to use a hyphen in column names. Try to use underscore instead. But still you can get the value by $company->getAttribute('start-time').

Answer (score 0):

if you are posting value as POST method

```
<form  method="POST" action="delete-blog">
<input type="text" name="form_value_for_city" />
</form>
```

in controller you can access like this

```
 public function deleteBlogPost(Request $request) {
        $request->form_value_for_city
        }
```

Also make sure you have imported `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in controller

in Route you have to add post route for this

```
Route::post('delete-blog','BlogController@deleteBlogPost');
```

For Get Request
in Route:

```
Route::get('edit-tag/{id}','BlogController@editTag');
```

in controller

```
public function editTag($id) {

        $response = Tag::retrieveTagById($id);


        return view('tag', ['data' => $response]);
    }
```

As per your Question if its post

```
->where ('company.city', '=', $request->form_value_for_city)
```

if its Get Then you have some think like this

```
public function test($form_value_for_city){
->where ('company.city', '=', $form_value_for_city)
}
```

Comment: Hard to understand, too detailed for me I guess :P I actually just used the request object, and it did what I wanted.